# What is the symbolism of the chess game between Ron and Harry in Goblet of Fire?

Tags: harry-potter

In Chapter 23, "The Yule Ball" of Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Ron and Harry play a game of chess while procrastinating as Harry doesn't feel like trying to figure out what the egg clue for the second task means. The book says the chess match "culminated in an exciting checkmate of Ron's, involving a couple of recklessly brave pawns and a very violent bishop."

As someone who took high school Literature and has many of the theories about the Harry Potter books on this site, this passage screams symbolism, but of what? Surely this chess match parallels or foreshadows something else that happens in the books, but I can't think of what it would be.

Has Rowling ever said what the symbolism is, or has she ever dispelled the notion that there is symbolism in the match? Are there events in the books excellent parallels for the chess match?

Comment: To me it's just cute details to flesh out the gameplay of wizard's chess and remind us we're in a magical world.

Comment: [Not everything is symbolic](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/s/sigmundfre377114.html). Smart writers often will try to write at least somewhat in a realistic style; in well-written books, as in life, sometimes interesting things happen that have no relation to the plot. In this particular case, this is merely meant to remind readers that magical chess has pieces with personalities.

Comment: Every time I read this I think of Ron and Harry as recklessly brave pawns. An answer already suggests it refers to Harry and Cedric, instead, which makes more sense. "Recklessly brave" isn't really a way to describe chess pawns that literally follow exact orders. Perhaps Ron's strategy. Specifically personifying the pieces, though, with characteristics that parallel Harry and people around him... I don't think there's reason to question OPs premise.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Why not? Not everything is symbolic. Rowling is known for including lots of quirky little details in her books, after all. Don't forget, a lot of authors (particularly those who haven't been corrupted by literary theory ;) ) are just trying to write characters acting as realistically (or sometimes, as entertainingly) as possible within the confines of their fictional world.

Comment: @Adamant If that's an answer, it belongs as an *answer*. There's no reason to essentially gang up on an OP in comments because you don't like their question. It's alienating, unwelcoming, and unhelpful.

Comment: @CreationEdge - There's no ganging up going on. I just don't think it's symbolism, and I'm saying it (not particularly unkindly, I thought, but maybe I'm wrong). But such a bare response as mine hardly deserves an answer (also, is it less "ganging up" as an answer?), particularly given that the OP asked what the symbolism was, not *whether* there was symbolism. On the other hand, you seem to have some ideas about the symbolism of this passage. Perhaps you could post an answer?

Comment: That said, there is a lot of symbolism in *Harry Potter*: alchemical symbolism, Christ symbolism, Grail symbolism, perhaps even symbolism in Harry's name, so this is definitely a question worth asking.

Comment: From what I know @Adamant may be right that there isn't any symbolism. That's why I included the question about whether Rowling had specifically said as much. If it really isn't symbolic of anything, but Rowling never said so, then I understand that perhaps the question doesn't have an answer.

Comment: I think the chess game was Rowling's way of saying 1) Ron is smarter than we might think - he's a recognised player of Wizard's Chess. 2) it foreshadows Ron being 'in charge' when the three youngster came across the chess challenge beneath the school. 3) it gives a reason to have Ron meet a challenge and important to the story. Hermione also met her challenge and then Harry goes on to meet his own.

Answer (score 5):

JK Rowling wrote this to tell the reader about Goblet of Fire's ending.

One can say that the 'recklessly brave pawns' refer to Harry and Cedric Diggory. The 'very violent bishop' would refer to Voldemort.

Comment: One might think Voldemort was the Dark King on the chessboard and the very violent bishop was Barty Crouch Jr.

Comment: Yes, Crouch/Moody seems like a better fit. Bishops are authority figures, which not-Moody was. Plus, they're all Ron's pieces which suggests the same "side", which for all everyone else knew, not-Moody was.

Comment: Crouch wasn't particularly violent though. And in this book Voldemort really wasn't checkmated.

You did open my eyes to a possibility that I hadn't considered - that the bishop was on the other team rather than on the same team as the pawns. That would seem to open up a lot more possibilities.

Comment: @Readin Crouch used unforgivable curses in class demos, killed his own father, attacked Fleur and Krum. Hard to say. I also haven't read that passage in a few years, now, so there could be another context, completely (such as foreshadowing a much smaller scale event).